# Calling localStorage.removeItem() inside beforeunload event is not working Properly

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to create a app Download Strip in react .When the page renders for the first time it should show app download strip but after the user click cross icon it should not occur again if someone click on any other link that routes to different product. Also if the user closes the tab and again visits the page it should work fine.

i tried to write the code taking local storage in the mind here is the code for every neccessary file and i expected that for the first time app-download strip will be visible and when someone cancels and move to another link in the website. app-strip-download should not be visible again.
Also if the user closes the tab and revists the page app-download strip should be visible again.

Just keep in miund the app-download-strip container is being called from the different locations as well so the code i wrote is focused around showing a app-strip-download only for the first time .
i am stuck at the part where i need to at the last need to clear local storage so that again when the user visits the page my logic could work fine .

Here are the neccessary files i wrote to make it happen .
for styling

```
const fadeInTop = keyframes`
    from {
        height: 0;
        
    }
    to {
        height: auto;
    }
`;


export const AppDownloadContainer = styled.div`
    animation: ${fadeInTop};
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    background-color: #ffa600;
    position: relative;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px;
    z-index: 10009;
    @media (min-width: 769px) {
        justify-content: center;
    }
    @media (min-width: 379px) {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: 62px;
    }
    @media (max-width: 378px) {
        text-align: center;
        min-height: 87px;
    }
`;
```

Component code

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showAppDownload: false
        };
    
    }
 componentDidMount() {
        console.log("inside component did mount line 42");
          if (window && Object.keys(window).length > 0) {
            let isShown = "isShown";
            console.log(window.localStorage.getItem(isShown),"line52");
            if (window.localStorage.getItem(isShown) === null) {
                console.log("Am i coming inside this ","Line 54");
                window.localStorage.setItem(isShown, true);
                   setTimeout(() => {
                   window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
                           window.localStorage.removeItem(isShown);
                   })
                   this.setState({ showAppDownload: true });
                }, 4000);

         }
       }
    }
```

```
hideAppDownload = () => {
        this.setState({ showAppDownload: false });
    };
```

```
{showAppDownload ? (
                    <AppDownloadContainer>
                        <AppDownloadContent>
                            Download the GoPaisa App Now and Get Exclusive Bonus Cashback Offers on
                            Flipkart and Amazon
                        </AppDownloadContent>
                        <a
                            target="_blank"
                            href="">
                            <DownloadAppImg
                                src=""
                                alt="Download GoPaisa App"
                            />
                        </a>
                        <CloseDownloadContent onClick={this.hideAppDownload}>
                            &#x2715;
                        </CloseDownloadContent>
                    </AppDownloadContainer>
                ) : (
                    ""
                )}
```

I really appreciate any help regarding this issue .
thanks .

Comment: You could use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) because the value is automatically deleted when the user closes the tab or browser.

Comment: Thanks For Replying @Yogi I will try it but according to the logic if i use session storage it will also get cleared once i navigate to some other link on the page as it got lost on reload of the page as well.

Comment: Thanks @Yogi it worked i was wrong about session storage .it persists on reloads and redirects and cleared on  closing tab